# Compact form - Partial derivative u^T M u

Tags: derivatives

fellows,

My question consist in: is there an identity for the following partial derivative?

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{x}} \left( \mathbf{u}^{\intercal} \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{u} \right)$

$\mathbf{u}$ does not depend on $\mathbf{x}$. I thank you sincerely.

Best regards.

Comment: If you work this out for $n=2$ or $n=3$, then in sigma notation for a general $n$, it's pretty clear what the formula has to be.

Comment: Please, if you know the answer, make it explicit. My question would go further if the above derivative has matrix compact form.

Comment: My early question would be if $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{q}} \mathbf{u}^{\intercal} \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q}) \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{u}^{\intercal}\frac{\partial \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{q})}{\partial \mathbf{q} \mathbf{u}$, with the partial derivative in the middle would be weird, but it looks like it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that $M: \mathbb{R}^n \to M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})$, is differentiable and that $u \in \Bbb{R^n}$ is fixed. Notice that $u^T M(x)u$ can be equivalently written using the standard inner product as
\begin{equation}
\langle M(x) \, u, u\rangle
\end{equation}
So, we are considering the function  $f: \Bbb{R^n} \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \langle M(x) \, u, u \rangle
\end{equation}
Since the inner product is bilinear, we can apply a kind of "generalised product rule" to compute the differential (or Frechet Derivative to be more specific) of $f$ at $x$ (which is a linear transformation from $\Bbb{R^n}$ into $\Bbb{R}$) as follows:
\begin{align}
df_x(\cdot) &= \langle dM_x(\cdot) \, u, u\rangle + \langle M(x) \, u, du_x(\cdot) \rangle \\
&= \langle dM_x(\cdot) \, u, u\rangle + 0 \\
&= \langle dM_x(\cdot) \, u, u\rangle
\end{align} 
The second term is $0$, because you said $u$ is a constant vector (hence it doesn't depend on $x$). This is pretty much the most compact form to write things in, because it is an equality of linear transformations which includes all the information about partial derivatives and directional derivatives.

However, if you really want to write things in terms of partial derivatives, here's what you do: to get the $i^{th}$ partial derivative of $f$ at $x$, we substitute the vector $e_i = (0, \dots, 1, \dots, 0)$ ($1$ in $i^{th}$ place) inside the open slot $(\cdot)$ above.

So,
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x) &= df_x(e_i) \\
&= \langle dM_x(e_i)\, u, u\rangle \\
&= \left \langle \dfrac{\partial M}{\partial x_i}(x) \, u, u \right \rangle
\end{align}

As a sanity check notice the following: by definition, the LHS has to be a real number. On the RHS, $\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial x_i}(x)$ is the $n \times n$ matrix obtained from $M$ by taking the $i^{th}$ partial derivative of each component function of $M$ and evaluating at $x$. So, multiplying with $u$ makes $\left[ \dfrac{\partial M}{\partial x_i}(x) \, u \right]$ a vector in $\Bbb{R}^n$. So the RHS is the inner product (or dot/scalar product if you like) of two vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$, and hence is a real number (just as predicted by the LHS).

---

Edit:

Here's an alternative proof to the one I presented above. Again, let $M,f,u$ be as above. Now, define a new map $\psi: M_{n \times n}(R) \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\psi(A) = u^T A u$. It is easy to see that $\psi$ is linear. Now, the function $f$ can be written as a composition:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = (\psi \circ M)(x)
\end{equation}
The multivariable chain rule now tells us that
\begin{equation}
df_x = d \psi_{M(x)} \circ dM_x 
\end{equation}
Since $\psi$ is linear, $d \psi_{M(x)} = \psi$ (this is an equality of linear transformations). Hence, we get
\begin{equation}
df_x = \psi \circ dM_x
\end{equation}
This equation may look different to the one above, but it's identical; you just have to unravel the definitions. Using the open-slot $(\cdot)$ notation, it says
\begin{equation}
df_x(\cdot) = u^T dM_x(\cdot) u
\end{equation}

Now, once again, if you want the partial derivatives, evaluate both sides on the vector $e_i$:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x) = df_x(e_i) = u^T dM_x(e_i) u = u^T \left[ \dfrac{\partial M}{\partial x_i}(x) \right] u,
\end{align}
which is exactly what we found above.

Comment: I appreciate the formal mathematical proof. Your profile name is coherent to the hide-and-seek game we play with math.

Comment: @Bruno if this answer is too formal for you, atleast the final answer for the partial derivative is given. So what you can (and should) do is to brute force it: multiply out all the matrices using sigma (summation) notation, take the partial derivative using the basic rules and then recombine terms to verify that the answer I proposed is indeed what you get.

Comment: The "formal" statement meant no harm. In fact, I appreciate neat formal explanations. Brute force is, although questionable, much less elegant than formalism.